# Unable to trace down rule in bootstrap scss

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I am investigating something I don't understand about bootstrap 4. I have the following snippet:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="pills" data-tabsetid="2812">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-2812-1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Load">Load</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab-2812-2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Remove">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The links look as pills and ordered vertically, which is what I want. What I don't understand is that, according to my browser inspect, the rule that defines the style of the links is the following

```
.nav-pills .nav-link, .nav-pills .nav-tabs > li > a, .nav-pills > li > a, .nav-pills 
ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

specifically, it matches `.nav-pills > li > a`, but I can't find any trace of that rule in the bootstrap source code, even considering the scss processing:

```
//
// Pills
//

.nav-pills {
  .nav-link {
    @include border-radius($nav-pills-border-radius);
  }

.nav-link.active,
  .show > .nav-link {
    color: $nav-pills-link-active-color;
    background-color: $nav-pills-link-active-bg;
  }
}
```

It surprised me because I was expecting it to fail because I was missing the nav-link specification, but it works anyway. How is it possible? Where is the matching rule defined in the scss?

I am using bootstrap 4.6.3

Comment: Can you add a working example? (I've tried to reproduce the behaviour that you've described, but the links did not display correctly without the proper classes, e.g. nav-link)

Comment: 1) Your `.nav-pills` didn't follow Bootstrap 4.6.x documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#pills). You need `.nav-item` on `<li />` and `.nav-link` on anchor tags. 2) from Bootstrap 4.x, it should have style `.nav-pills .nav-link` for border-radius. Those kind of tell me you might not be using Bootstrap 4.x, at least solely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you loading more than one version of Bootstrap? The rules you are seeing look like they're from [Bootstrap v3](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css):

```css
.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an visual example to refer to, but this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cc404/pen/abBppMZ), where I've loaded both 4.6.x and 3.4.1, might look similar to what OP explained.

Comment: That is a possibility which I have to check, but then, how come I get a border-radius only and not also the rest from bootstrap 3?

Comment: More exactly, it looks like coming from the file  bootstrap/3.4.1/css/less/navs.less